# Vite React MUI SSR Error - Expected server HTML to contain a matching <div> in <div>

Tags: material-ui, server-side-rendering, vite

I am trying to integrate Vite SSR with MUI and I am facing warning and errors when I run the "dev:server" command.

> Expected server HTML to contain a matching  in

> Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

This is my codebase

entry-client.tsx

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { createBrowserRouter, matchRoutes, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";

import { routes } from "./App";
import createEmotionCache from "../../createEmotionCache";
import { CacheProvider } from "@emotion/react";
import { theme } from "../../theme";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material";
const cache = createEmotionCache();

async function hydrate() {
  // Determine if any of the initial routes are lazy
  let lazyMatches = matchRoutes(routes, window.location)?.filter(m => m.route.lazy);

  // Load the lazy matches and update the routes before creating your router
  // so we can hydrate the SSR-rendered content synchronously
  if (lazyMatches && lazyMatches?.length > 0) {
    await Promise.all(
      lazyMatches.map(async m => {
        let routeModule = await m.route.lazy!();
        Object.assign(m.route, { ...routeModule, lazy: undefined });
      }),
    );
  }

  let router = createBrowserRouter(routes);

  ReactDOM.hydrateRoot(
    document.getElementById("app")!,
    <React.StrictMode>
      <CacheProvider value={cache}>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme()}>
          <RouterProvider router={router} fallbackElement={null} />
        </ThemeProvider>
      </CacheProvider>
    </React.StrictMode>,
  );
}

hydrate();
```

entry-server.tsx

```
import type * as express from "express";
import * as React from "react";
import ReactDOMServer from "react-dom/server";
import { createStaticHandler, createStaticRouter, StaticRouterProvider } from "react-router-dom/server";
import { routes } from "./App";
import createEmotionCache from "../../createEmotionCache";
import createEmotionServer from "@emotion/server/create-instance";
import { CssBaseline, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material";
import { CacheProvider } from "@emotion/react";
import { theme } from "../../theme";

export function createFetchRequest(req: express.Request): Request {
  let origin = `${req.protocol}://${req.get("host")}`;
  // Note: This had to take originalUrl into account for presumably vite's proxying
  let url = new URL(req.originalUrl || req.url, origin);

  let controller = new AbortController();
  req.on("close", () => controller.abort());

  let headers = new Headers();

  for (let [key, values] of Object.entries(req.headers)) {
    if (values) {
      if (Array.isArray(values)) {
        for (let value of values) {
          headers.append(key, value);
        }
      } else {
        headers.set(key, values);
      }
    }
  }

  let init: RequestInit = {
    method: req.method,
    headers,
    signal: controller.signal,
  };

  if (req.method !== "GET" && req.method !== "HEAD") {
    init.body = req.body;
  }

  return new Request(url.href, init);
}

export async function render(request: express.Request) {
  const cache = createEmotionCache();
  const { extractCriticalToChunks, constructStyleTagsFromChunks } = createEmotionServer(cache);
  let { query, dataRoutes } = createStaticHandler(routes);
  let remixRequest = createFetchRequest(request);
  let context = await query(remixRequest);

  if (context instanceof Response) {
    throw context;
  }

  let router = createStaticRouter(dataRoutes, context);
  const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
    <CacheProvider value={cache}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme(request)}>
        {/* CssBaseline kickstart an elegant, consistent, and simple baseline to build upon. */}
        <CssBaseline />
        <StaticRouterProvider router={router} context={context} nonce="the-nonce" />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </CacheProvider>,
  );

  const emotionChunks = extractCriticalToChunks(html);
  const emotionCss = constructStyleTagsFromChunks(emotionChunks);

  return {
    html,
    css: emotionCss,
  };
}
```

server.ts

```
import type { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";
import fs from "fs/promises";
import path from "path";
import express from "express";
import compression from "compression";
import serveStatic from "serve-static";
import { createServer as createViteServer } from "vite";
const isTest = process.env.NODE_ENV === "test" || !!process.env.VITE_TEST_BUILD;

const resolve = (p: string) => path.resolve(__dirname, p);

const getStyleSheets = async () => {
  try {
    const assetpath = resolve("dist/assets");
    const files = await fs.readdir(assetpath);
    const cssAssets = files.filter(l => l.endsWith(".css"));
    const allContent = [];
    for (const asset of cssAssets) {
      const content = await fs.readFile(path.join(assetpath, asset), "utf-8");
      allContent.push(`<style type="text/css">${content}</style>`);
    }
    return allContent.join("\n");
  } catch {
    return "";
  }
};

async function createServer(isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  const app = express();
  // Create Vite server in middleware mode and configure the app type as
  // 'custom', disabling Vite's own HTML serving logic so parent server
  // can take control
  const vite = await createViteServer({
    server: { middlewareMode: true },
    appType: "custom",
    logLevel: isTest ? "error" : "info",
  });

  // use vite's connect instance as middleware
  // if you use your own express router (express.Router()), you should use router.use
  app.use(vite.middlewares);
  const requestHandler = express.static(resolve("assets"));
  app.use(requestHandler);
  app.use("/assets", requestHandler);

  if (isProd) {
    app.use(compression());
    app.use(
      serveStatic(resolve("dist/client"), {
        index: false,
      }),
    );
  }
  const stylesheets = getStyleSheets();
  app.use("*", async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const url = req.originalUrl;

    try {
      // 1. Read index.html
      let template = await fs.readFile(isProd ? resolve("dist/client/index.html") : resolve("index.html"), "utf-8");

      // 2. Apply Vite HTML transforms. This injects the Vite HMR client, and
      //    also applies HTML transforms from Vite plugins, e.g. global preambles
      //    from @vitejs/plugin-react
      template = await vite.transformIndexHtml(url, template);

      // 3. Load the server entry. vite.ssrLoadModule automatically transforms
      //    your ESM source code to be usable in Node.js! There is no bundling
      //    required, and provides efficient invalidation similar to HMR.
      let productionBuildPath = path.join(__dirname, "./dist/server/entry-server.mjs");
      let devBuildPath = path.join(__dirname, "./src/client/entry-server.tsx");
      const { render } = await vite.ssrLoadModule(isProd ? productionBuildPath : devBuildPath);

      // 4. render the app HTML. This assumes entry-server.js's exported `render`
      //    function calls appropriate framework SSR APIs,
      //    e.g. ReactDOMServer.renderToString()
      const appHtml = await render(req);
      console.log('appHtml', appHtml)
      const cssAssets = appHtml.css;

      // 5. Inject the app-rendered HTML into the template.
      const html = template.replace(`<!--app-html-->`, appHtml.html).replace(`<!--head-->`, cssAssets);

      // 6. Send the rendered HTML back.
      res.status(200).set({ "Content-Type": "text/html" }).end(html);
    } catch (e: any) {
      !isProd && vite.ssrFixStacktrace(e);
      console.log(e.stack);
      // If an error is caught, let Vite fix the stack trace so it maps back to
      // your actual source code.
      vite.ssrFixStacktrace(e);
      next(e);
    }
  });
  const port = process.env.PORT || 7456;
  app.listen(Number(port), "0.0.0.0", () => {
    console.log(`App is listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

createServer();
```

[image]

For some reason, I am unable to run "dev:server" on stackblitz.

Here is the link to Stackblitz: https://codesandbox.io/p/github/arunmmanoharan/vite-ssr-sample/main?file=/src/client/components/Footer/index.tsx:1,1&workspaceId=7f6d11d1-b8c5-4ac3-a516-45c2abdc45e3

Here is the link to the github repo: https://github.com/arunmmanoharan/vite-ssr-sample

Please advice.